# How to resize the image to be uploaded in JSP to a fix resolution?

Tags: image, jsp

I am uploading images for my site , I want every image uploaded to the server be of constant size.
So, when I display them from server to my site they can be uploaded quickly and the images use less server space.

code I am using to upload image using JSP.

```
logo_name = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
            File  uploadedFile = new File("/www/static.appcanvas.com/"+logo_name);
            item.write(uploadedFile);
```

Any related articles , some hints will be of great help

Comment: I have a ImageFix class which returns the resized image

Comment: So what's the problem? Use that class to resize the image. I don't see a question here.

Comment: I am able to get the resized image while displaying them from server. not while uploading to the server. I intend to have images with same resolution tored in the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show us how you are parsing the upload. But, if "item is a org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem  then you could use something lik the following.

```
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(item.getInputStream()); 
Image img = bi.getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
int w = img.getWidth();
int h = img.getHeight();  
BufferedImage scaled = new BufferedImage(w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);       
Graphics2D g = scaled.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(img,0,0,null); 
if(g != null) g.dispose();
ImageIO.write(scaled,"png", uploadedFile);
```

Comment: this reduces the image resolution according to my needs but there is a additional black background to the image which have resolution less than required.